# When I move the torus，the “Add Torus” menu disappears

Tags: mesh

When I add a **Torus** through the `Shift` + `A` dropdown, there's a dropdown menu where I can adjust the torus parameters.

However, when I move it, the menu disappears.

How can I bring it back?

Comment: You can't as soon as you've made an action (like moving the object), if you want a non-destructive primitive, I think it's possible with Geometry Nodes

Comment: As @moonboots says, if you've done anything other than click an empty section of the 3D window your only option is to X > Delete the torus and add another one. If you've **only** clicked away from it, you can bring back a popup menu with F9.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!Oh!I understand. It means that if I do an action , I can't open the ADD TORUS.Is this correct?

Comment: @seadog It's basically a modification menu, and this goes for all objects. You can't modify them if you have done two moves. With one move, you can still bring it back.

Comment: @Yousuf Chaudhry Thank you!This made me understand! Thank you!！！！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call the `Add Torus` menu is actually the `Adjust Last Operation` menu.

> After an operation is complete you can tweak the parameters of
> Operators afterwards. In editors that support it, there is a “head-up
> display” panel in the bottom left based on the last performed
> operation; dependent on mode and context. Alternatively, you can
> create a pop-up with <kbd>F9</kbd> which does the same thing.
>
> Source: [**Undo & Redo — Blender Manual**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/undo_redo.html#adjust-last-operation)

By design, it is meant to tweak whatever the latest action you did. Moving the torus is a new operation, so this menu will show you what you need to tweak the move operation.
There is no way to make this menu go back in time to this day, so you have to make decisive actions all the time.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: @seadog If the answer solved your problem, accept it by clicking the checkbox on the top left corner.

Comment: @Yousuf Chaudhry Thank you! My first time using this site